# VMware не может получить IP-адрес

Tags: битрикс, centos, vmware, виртуальная-машина

Всем добрый вечер! Вчера пытался зайти на IP-адрес локального сервера, но неожиданно понял, что у меня его нет. Перезагрузка VMBitrix также не помогла. 
[image: Ошибка VMware]

Скорее всего это связано с тем, что я подключался к сети в Университете. Благодаря этому сбились настройки.
Советуют переустановить VMware. Подскажите, сайт, который я делал на локальной машине, сохранится?

`ifconfig` выдает следующее:
[image: IFCONFIG]

Comment: вероятно, стоит уточнить, что у вас используется в качестве гостевой и основной систем.

Comment: Всегда пользуюсь MacOS. Для локальной разработки сайта поставил CentOS с 1С-Битрикс.

Comment: *Советуют переустановить VMware* — ну, да, *windows-way* может и привести к успеху. но, возможно, в используемой вами программе для виртуализации можно всего лишь перенастроить сетевые параметры гостевой системы.

Answer (score 2):

Как оказалось, данная проблема решается очень просто. Нужно сменить режим сетевого подключения на NAT.